# jQuery load content into tab after form submit

Tags: php, jquery-ui

i'd like to load the action of a form in the same tab that it's been called from. i have a main page as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs(
        );
    }); 
</script>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="page1.php">page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.php">page2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

on page1.php and page2.php i have different forms.
in page1.php for example:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="page1.php" method="post">
/* form components */
</form>
```

basically the form reload the page itself and populate a div underneath.
how can i do the submit on the tab (and refresh it)? right now by submitting the form page1.php gets load in a new window.
i tried with this snippet that i found searching in stackoverflow but with no luck

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '#form1', function() {

var data = $(this).serialize();
var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action');

$.post(actionUrl, data, function(response) {
    /* do something when form submittal completed*/   
})

return false; /* prevent browser default submit and redirect*/
});
</script>
```

Comment: like `$('#divID').html(response);`?

Comment: If i enclose all page1.PHP in divID and add tour code in the .post call i get redirected to page1.PHP in a new pace of the browser andò noto in the tab on the dame page ad i'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by adding at the page loaded from the tab the following code

```
$('#formID').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var formSrc = $(this).attr('action');
var formMethod = $(this).attr('method');
var formData = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
  url: formSrc,
  type: formMethod,
  data: formData,
  success: function(data){
    //work with returned data from requested file
    $("#divID").html(data);
  }
});
```

});